# What technologies are suitable for building Queue Management Systems?

Tags: programming-languages, queue

I figure out some technologies that can help me to build Queue Management Systems. Each terminal will send multicast to others. All the terminals get messaging in sync in real time. I'm not sure that do I really need a database server as backend or not?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details.

Comment: @Nifle, I need to find out messaging technology, How to keep all nodes in sync.

Answer (score -1):

I would say not. After all a database is just a store of data, you can achieve much the same using a binary datafile.

Still the technology that you use will depend on:

1. Operating system
2. Network connection and type.
3. Terminal architecture e.g. local storage.
4. Do you actually need a server?